# How to Auto-Alignment Shortcut Key in Keil uVision?

Tags: alignment, keyboard-shortcuts, edit, keil, autoformatting

I want to find Auto-Alignment Shortcut Key in Keil uVision. I tried some shortcut keys but I can not find. In Visual Studio I used to: CTRL + K + D , but in keil uVision I don't know how it is work.

For example :

When you type below ( usually copied from another text file which was not tabified correctly):

[image]

Use the shortcut key Auto Alignment with this block of code can auto formatting your code as below :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Stop searching. There is no such feature.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to align in uVision5 with Astyle (http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).

File must be saved so that this tool can do its work.

Instructions :

Copy the Astyle.exe file to the Keil installation directory (e.g. D:/Keil_v5/)

Then open Keil and under the Tools menu, open the Customize Tools Menu option.

Create a new Menu Content, the name can be casual .

Command selects the Astyle.exe file in the keil installation directory.

Fill in Arguments !E

You can add a shortcut key for the operation in Edit.

Cheers to this https://www.programmersought.com/article/578892324/